# Can someone help me understand how this Python code works

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is code is an from a lesson i'm doing in class at school and i'm confused about how the list gets printed because it keeps ending with "None"...

```
def printlist(myList, pointer):
    print("The List is: ", myList)
    print("Pointer length: ", pointer)
    print("The List length is: ", len(myList))
    print("The List printed properly:")
    print(printlistproperly(myList))

def printlistproperly(myList):
    thelength = len(myList)
    for i in range(thelength):
        print(i, " ", myList[i])

def popin(myList,pointer):
    myList.append(input("Enter a value: "))
    pointer = len(myList)-1
    return myList, pointer

def main():
    myList = ["Ford","Toyota","Mustang"]
    pointer = len(myList)-1
    myList,pointer = popin(myList,pointer)
    printlist(myList, pointer)
```

The results are:

```
>>> main()
Enter a value: Dodge
The List is:  ['Ford', 'Toyota', 'Mustang', 'Dodge']
Pointer length:  3
The List length is:  4
The List printed properly:
0   Ford
1   Toyota
2   Mustang
3   Dodge
None
```

My real problem is... What's the None at the end?? Where does it come from? How can I fix it?

Comment: Alex already answered correctly. Just my two cents: In python you almost never need to iterate over `range(len(lst))`. In your case (inside `printlistpropertly`) you can simply write: `for i, e in enumerate(MyList): print (i, ' ', e)`.

Comment: What is the `popin()` expected to do? What is the reason for the `pointer` variable?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the function `printlist` you print the result of the function `printlistproperly`, which returns nothing. Therefore you get the `None`. Solution: Just call `printlistproperly(myList)` (without the `print`).

```
def printlist(myList, pointer):
    print("The List is: ", myList)
    print("Pointer length: ", pointer)
    print("The List length is: ", len(myList))
    print("The List printed properly:")
    printlistproperly(myList)
```

Comment: "print the function", no, he prints the *result* of the function. That's completely different.

Comment: My +1. If a function does not contain the `return something` command or if it contains `return` without argument, it behaves the same way as if it ended with `return None`.